# ListView.builder itemBuilder function re-executes on scroll after list is created

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a `ListView.builder` that builds a list of random images from [PicsumPhotos](https://picsum.photos).

Everything works as expected, expect for a strange behaviour with scroll. **Once the list is fully rendered**, if I scroll up or scroll down, the `itemBuilder` function fires once (once for scroll up, and once for scroll down), causing fetching a new first image (when scroll up) and a new last image (when scroll down).

I'm missing something? Thanks in advance.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:components_demo/shared/components/appbar_back.dart';

class ListViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ListViewPageState();
}

class _ListViewPageState extends State<ListViewPage> {
  int itemCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setItemCount();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBarBack('ListView'), body: _createList());
  }

  Widget _createList() {
    final random = Random();
    return ListView.builder(
      key: Key('myList'),
      itemCount: itemCount,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { // when scroll up/down, fires once
        final photoIndex = random.nextInt(250);
        print(photoIndex);
        return FadeInImage(
          image: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/id/$photoIndex/500/300').image,
          placeholder: Image.asset('assets/jar-loading.gif').image,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _setItemCount() {
    setState(() {
      itemCount = 5;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your image a `UniqueKey`. The item builder doesn’t know it’s the same widget because it can’t identify it.

```dart
FadeInImage(
  key: UniqueKey(),
),
```

Comment: Thanks. Still happen 

Comment: I think I understand what happen. Every time I scrolling back from a out of view point, the list re-renders the out of view widget.

Comment: You're also using a method to return a widget, that also makes it rebuild more often than necessary. You should extract a widget into another stateless or statefull widget